# Proving the generator of $A = \{154a + 210b : a,b \in\mathbb Z\}$ is $(154, 210)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am trying to prove the generator of $A = \{154a + 210b : a,b \in\mathbb Z\}$ is $(154, 210)$.

For both negative or positive $a,b$ the proof is trivial. My trouble is what happend when $a > 0$ and $0 > b$ - Given $a > 0, b < 0$ show there exist some $k$ such that $2^k = 210a + 154b$.

$(154, 210) = 14$.

We know that if $(154, 210) = 14$ then there exist $x,y$ such that $154x + 210y = 14$.

How can i use this to show that given some $a,b$ and $154a + 210b = 14^k$ for some $k$?

Im not even sure its the right direction.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you try to rephrase it?

Comment: Proving the generator of $A$ is $lcm(154,210)$ @JoséCarlosSantos

Comment: And what is the generator of a set of integer numbers?

Comment: Please give statement of the problem *exactly* as it is stated in the source.

Comment: You might want to check that _lcm_ is **not** the abbreviation for "greatest common divisor". // Also you might want to check the type of (semi-)group you want to generate, if it is the additive or the multiplicative variant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the further proof , you just need to show that $154a + 210b$ just generates all the common multiples of $154$ and $210$ for different values of $a$ and $b$ where $a , b \in \mathbb Z$ in which HCF of these two numbers will be the smallest possible Linear combination of $154a + 210b$ for a particular choice of $a$ and $b$ . And HCF obviously generate all the common multiples then.